# Emulator with GPU, forever loading

Tags: android

There are many questions about having problem with GPU, some got solved, some didn't. But I'm still looking to fix mine.

Here is what happened, first, I had to enabled the HAX by changing the value of a specific offset, cause SONY didn't allow user to enable it by BIOS. After that I installed the HAXM downloaded by SDK Manager Revision 21.1 . Everything went well, chose 1024MB for it. Checked in CMD, intehaxm service was running. Yet whenever I run emulator with GPU on, it just keep show black screen and takes around 800 MB of ram and 50% of CPU, which makes the laptop quite laggy. Without GPU that emulator works good, but too slow.

Settings I used were

[image: Android Emulator Settings]

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but what is SDK #21? Did you mean API revision 17?

Comment: SDK Manager Revision 21.1 :)